# Symbolize_keys Issue with Paperclip- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, paperclip

When I run this line of code in my view,

```
<%= image_tag(item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo") %>
```

I get a

```
 undefined method `symbolize_keys'
```

error. I'm currently using the paperclip gem with S3 storage. Any suggestions?

-- Edit:

Here is what the server log says:

```
Started GET "/items/compare" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-19 14:47:21 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#compare as HTML
(0.1ms)  SELECT items.id FROM "items" 
Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" IN (3, 2)
Rendered items/compare.html.erb within layouts/application (37.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x007f9ebccd92b0>):
3: <% @items.each do |item| %>
4:  <div class="item<%= loopcount %>">
5:      <% loopcount = loopcount +1%>
6:      <%= image_tag(item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo") %> <blockquote>     </blockquote>
7:      <h2 class = "iteminfotext"><%= item.votes %></h2>
8:      <h1 class = "iteminfotext"><%= item.location %></h1>
9:      <div class="iteminfotext"><%= button_to "Vote", :action => "vote", :id => item.id, %></div>
app/views/items/compare.html.erb:6:in `block in _   app_views_items_compare_html_erb___818922328118740053_70159882605160'
app/views/items/compare.html.erb:3:in `each'
app/views/items/compare.html.erb:3:in `  _app_views_items_compare_html_erb___818922328118740053_70159882605160'

Rendered /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-  3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.8ms)
```

Comment: Can you add the entire backtrace?

Comment: Does `Item.first.picture.url(:medium)` work in the console

Comment: Also, unrelated but have a look at [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index), a little cleaner than manually setting a loopcount

Comment: Thanks for the each_with_index tip! I always found that snippet incredibly ugly, but I didn't know a better way.
To be honest, I don't think it will. My database is kind of a nightmare and a dead laptop isn't letting me check at the moment. Do you think that could be a cause?

Comment: If it doesn't work in the console then it's not a view problem at all, that would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Excellent point. It doesn't work in console. Not even a simple @item.picture.url works. It still gives the synbolize_keys error message. Honestly, it won't let me do anything. Creates, destroys all seem to point to a symbolize_keys message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a rails or paperclip issue. If you do

```
<%= image_tag(item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo") %>
```

it would not work unless you change it to a link like

```
<%= link_to image_tag(item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo"), item_path(item) %>
```

else you would always be getting the

```
undefined method `symbolize_keys'
```

to avoid this, all you have to do is reconstruct your image tag block  to look like this

```
 <%= image_tag(item.picture.url(:medium)), :class => "iteminfo" %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag(item.picture(:medium)), :class => "iteminfo" %>
```

then your problem is solved

update:

```
<%= image_tag item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo" %>
<%= image_tag item.picture(:medium), :class => "iteminfo" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It really is appreciated. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite seem to work. The bottom two lines oddly enough complain about about the comma between medium and class, while the link_to line still results in a symbolize_keys error.

Comment: I'm currently on Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: just updated it so it should work. but if you r using rubymine ide it should auto-complete it to fit the right syntax for you if it dosent then you r not getting it right.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It actually turned out that it was an error with a yaml file. The code you gave worked perfectly. Thank you again for everything.